# I have a separate class library created for commonlogic and a program.cs from where I call methods of that class

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a separate class library named CommonLogic.cs and using it in Program.cs
If I created a object from class Matrices i.e. Matrices mat = new Matrices and try to use it in Program.cs, I am not able to use the object i.e. mat.AdditionOfMatrix_Array()

It gives error. Can anyone guide as to what is wrong.

```
Program.cs
using CommonLogic;
using System;


namespace UseArrayArrayList_ListForMatrix

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int m, n, i, j = 0;
        char ch;

        int[,] Add = new int[10, 10];
        Add[i, j] = Matrices.AdditionOfMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, A, B, Add);
        Console.Write("\nSum Matrix :\n");
        Matrices.PrintMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, Add);
        break;
```

```
CommonLogic.cs
using System;

namespace ArrayArrayList_ListForMatrix
{
    public class Matrices
    {

        public static int AdditionOfMatrix_Array(int i, int j, int m, int n, int[,] X, int[,] Y, int[,] Z)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Z[i, j] = X[i, j] + Y[i, j];
                }
            }
            return Z[i, j];
```

Comment: Did you ```include``` it

Comment: You can't because your method is static. You can use directly by class name. Method name

Comment: @AmitVerma - Thanks for the advise! So what should I use  so that I can use the statement as mentioned in my question!

Comment: Remove static keyword from AdditionOfMatrix_Array method

Comment: FYI when "it gives error", please add details *about* that error (copy the text exactly, do not just describe it) - usually the error message points to the problem and its solution

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem in the provided code - `Matrices.AdditionOfMatrix_Array` is in `ArrayArrayList_ListForMatrix` namespace, you should add appropriate using, i.e. change `using CommonLogic;` to `using ArrayArrayList_ListForMatrix;` (or just add `using ArrayArrayList_ListForMatrix;` if you are using something from `CommonLogic` namespace) or change namespace for `Matrices` class to `CommonLogic`.

See also:

- [Declare namespaces to organize types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/namespaces)
- [`namespace` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace)

Also I would recommend following [C# coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code.

you are not defining or initializing the arrays `A` and `B`.

and based on your code, I think you want to iterate for `i` and `j`, something like below.

```
int m = 3, n = 3;
int[,] A = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
int[,] B = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
int[,] Add = new int[10, 10];

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        Add[i, j] = Matrices.AdditionOfMatrix_Array(i, j, m, n, A, B, Add);
    }
}
```

Also, you have `break;` in the `Main` method without any loop, which will give a compilation error.

Also, a small suggestion, If you are not using the return value of method `AdditionOfMatrix_Array` and only updating it, then you can return `void` in place of `int`.